# sorting using bubble sort method in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Why do we need to have sorted to be alternated between true and false values for the following code?

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    sorted = false

        until sorted 
            sorted = true
            (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
                if arr[i]  > arr[i + 1]
                    arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
                    sorted = false
                end
            end
        end

        arr  

    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Bubble sort terminates when a pass is made with no swaps.  This code starts a pass by assuming that the list is sorted:

```
sorted = true
```

But then, if a swap is made, decides that the list is not sorted after all:

```
if arr[i]  > arr[i + 1]
  arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
  sorted = false
end
```

In a way, the name of this variable is a lie, for a brief moment: After the penultimate pass, the last pass that does any swaps, "sorted" is false even though the array is fully sorted.  The last pass, the one that iterates over the sorted array, will then set "sorted" to true.

Comment: "Bubble sort terminates when a pass is made with no swaps". Answered all the question I had in my mined. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TesfaZelalem You are quite welcome.  There is a checkmark you can click on to mark this answer as "accepted," if you wish.